# Unused dummy argument and Return value of function not set

Tags: fortran

This is my Fortran 90 program for Newton-Raphson method. However, it did not compile properly and gave this warning in geany

```
newraph.f90:18.17:
real function f(x)
                 1
Warning: Unused dummy argument 'x' at (1)
newraph.f90:18.15:
real function f(x)
               1
Warning: Return value of function 'f' at (1) not set
Compilation finished successfully.
```

```
        program newton_raphson
        implicit none
        real,parameter::error=1e-4
        integer::i
        real::xo,x1,f,fd
        read*,xo
        i=1
        10 x1=xo-(f(xo)/fd(xo))
        if(abs((x1-xo)/x1)<error) then
        print*,"root is", x1,"no. of iteration=",i
        else
        xo=x1
        i=i+1
        goto 10
        endif
        end

        real function f(x)
        real::x
        end

        real function fd(x)
        real::x
        fd=3*x**2-1
        end
```

Answer (score 2):

You have just two warnings. Both just inform you that the function `f` does nothing:

```
    real function f(x)
    real::x
    end
```

Change it to return something useful and the warnings will vanish.

```
    real function f(x)
      real, intent(in)  :: x
      f = x**2
    end function
```

and then change `fd` to return the derivative of `f`, like `fd = 2*x`.

Other than that, try to use some decent programming style. Use indentation, use loops instead of `go to` where possible. Use vertical spacing (empty lines). Also it is better to use `end function`, `end subroutine` and `end program` for clarity.

Comment: Any suggestion since I just copied this program from a notebook and just ran it.

Comment: [Possibly `f` should have a result like `f=x**3-x+27.6`.]

Comment: @francescalus indeed, if `fd` is the derivative of `f`. Or change `fd` to `fd=2*x`.